# Like voice over for Android

Tags: android

Good day to all!

I'm trying to implement a voice over for Android (like iPhone), but a specific application (not the entire operating system)

Imagine a screen with six buttons, so they occupy the entire activity, distributed equally in size.

When I "walk" with my finger on the screen, I want to give focus to the button and capture the event when the button has focus and let the focus as well.

Conclusion: As I flick on the screen and if it is over a button, the focus button. if I continue to drag the finger, give the focus to another button without taking your finger off the screen.

Can anyone help me? Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the Android Button class for this, but instead do a custom view, draw six rectangles, and write an onTouchEvent method that determines what sound to play based on where the user's finger is. See the Sudokuv4 example at http://pragprog.com/book/eband3/hello-android for some code you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to know positions of buttons. You can use basic view functions to get positions (getLeft(), and so on...)

After that you have to implment onTouchListner for Activity. Within you have to check where Event.x and Event.y pointers are and set foucs to specified view. After pointers move from specified view you set focus to false.

Comment: Set ontouch listner for rootView and in it use event.getRawY() and event.getRawX(). This will let you know where touch happend. You have to write your own funnction which will check if event happend with in buttons based on getLeft(), getTop() and other functions. After that you can use setPressed(true) function of an button. Also in touch listner you have to determin if event is ACTION_DOWN or ACTION_UP. On first one you will be using setpressed(true) to view on second one you will be using setpressed(false). Look for some touch events tutorial